# Print all id numbers from class in http-request

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, httprequest

I would like to have a ready-made list containing id numbers.

```
<dl class="welcome" id="fdgvs_4455256765">
<dl class="welcome" id="34wfdsf_235250861">
<dl class="welcome" id="v3dr234fz_1242566862">
```

I already have a piece of code, but I miss the cut from the same id numbers.

```
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession

...

links = response.html.find(".welcome")
for one in links:
    divone = response.html.find('.id')
    print(one)
```

Output:

```
<Element 'dl' class=('welcome',) id='fdgvs_4455256765'>
<Element 'dl' class=('welcome',) id='34wfdsf_235250861'>
<Element 'dl' class=('welcome',) id='v3dr234fz_1242566862'>
```

What i want?:

```
4455256765
235250861
1242566862
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You split the string by `id=`, then you split the second part by `_` then you print the result by removing `'>` at the end.

```
str = "<Element 'dl' class=('welcome',) id='v3dr234fz_1242566862'>"

print(str.split("id=")[1].split("_")[1][:-2])
```